# view date in three input field as day month & year in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

### Well In Database Store dob as date format like m/d/y. I want Show On html Page In 3 differt Field Day field, Month field, Year Field. i Tried {{Auth::user()->dob[month]}} but Not working in laravel.please suggest me how can i display date in 3 diffrent field.

---

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <label for="dob_month" class="sr-only">Month</label>
      <select name = "month" id="m" class="form-control" value="{{Auth::user()->dob['month']}}"/>
           <option value="">Month</option>      
            @for ($month = 1; $month <= 12 ; $month++)                  
            <option value = "{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>                  
            @endfor
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: If the database is the date datatype date or some other datatype?

Comment: Date Datatype in database

Comment: please show one value of  date saved in database

Comment: also show `Auth::user()->dob[month]` in your user model

Comment: @SaurabhMistry      value is 1996-03-15    and yes this is in user model

Comment: protected $fillable   = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'zipcode', 'password', 'gender', 'lat', 'lng', 'city', 'state', 'address', 'dob', 'health',];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name = "month" id="m" class="form-control" value=""/>
   <option value=" {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->dob)->format('m')}}"> 
    {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->dob)->format('m')}}
   </option>      
   @for ($month = 1; $month <= 12 ; $month++)                  
     <option value = "{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>                  
  @endfor
</select>

Try This It Will Work for You
```

Answer (score 1):

Where `dob` is a field stored in the Database as a date, and a record is queried that contains the field through the Eloquent model it gets implicitly converted to an instance of `Carbon\Carbon`.

Note that the `month` property cannot be retrieved as using array index access on the instance but only via [object property getters](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) as:

```php
Auth::user()->dob->month
```

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60088272/11469255

Answer (score 1):

get month value like this way :

> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',Auth::user()->dob)->format('m')

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
         <label for="dob_month" class="sr-only">Month</label>
           <select name = "month" id="m" class="form-control"/>
           <option value="">Month</option>
            @for ($month = 1; $month <= 12 ; $month++)                                                
              @if($month==\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',Auth::user()->dob)->format('m'))
            <option value = "{{ $month }}" selected>{{ $month }}</option>
            @else
            <option value = "{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>
            @endif
            @endfor
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60088272/11469255